# php selecting an order from a different mysql table

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to retrieve my topics from table topics but in my look up list I want the most recent active topic to be showing, all the comments are in different table. How could I do it that my list shows all the topics from the topics table but puts them in order according to the most recent date from the comments table?

```
$forums = mysql_query("select * from forumtopic where category='$who' order by date DESC LIMIT " . (($page - 1) * 10) . ", 10");
```

while($forum = mysql_fetch_array($forums))
{

so I want it to be like

```
$forums = mysql_query("select * from forumtopic where category='$who' and select from forumcomment where category='$who' but order by date from forumcomment DESC LIMIT " . (($page - 1) * 10) . ", 10");
```

while($forum = mysql_fetch_array($forums))
{

if that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you wanted to do:

```
SELECT * FROM forumtopic 
WHERE category='$who' 
ORDER BY FIELD( topic,
    (SELECT topic 
    FROM forumcomment 
    WHERE category='$who' 
    ORDER BY date DESC)) 
LIMIT " . (($page - 1) * 10) . ", 10
```

The order by field lets you specify an order for the table forumtopic, which is ordered by most active, also I don't know the schema of your table so you have to change the names accordingly

EDIT - SIMPLER SOLUTION, JOIN THEN ORDER BY

```
SELECT forumtopic.topic FROM forumtopic
INNER JOIN forumcomment
ON forumtopic.topic = forumcomment.topic
WHERE category = '$who'
ORDER BY forumcomment.date DESC
LIMIT " . (($page - 1) * 10) . ", 10
```

Comment: awh I never learn that before, I am very grateful as it opens my eyes up to even more possibilities in my learning process

Comment: I added another version that you could try if the first doesn't work, you can merge the two tables, and order by the date, I don't know if the first one will work since I never tried it but let me know